# PHP - check / compare input from textfield

Tags: php, compare, textfield

Until now I had a PHP Kontaktform with empty textfields and checked the needed fields with:

`$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Please enter a Name.");`

Now the lable "your name" is in it the textfield itself. So the value is not empty anymore.
How do I check if there's still only "your name" in the field instead of a real name?

Thank you
(sorry php-noob)

Comment: Erhmm..... `if($name === "Please enter a Name.")`?

Comment: @nile - isn't there a "your name" missing, or does it check the standard value by itself?

Comment: you can rather use placeholder attribute in the text box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the HTML5 placeholder tag in the first place.

```
<input placeholder="Your Name" value="" name="name">
```

or, if that is not possible, check for that given string:

```
$name = (strstr('your name', $_POST['name']) ? '' : check_input($_POST['name'], "Please enter a Name."));
```

Comment: there are several polyfills for ie8 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

Compare `$name` to `"your name"`. If they are the same, then you didn't get an actual name.

for example

```
if ($name == "your name") {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // they have a valid name
}
```

Comment: This is exacly, what I was looking for. Thank you. ...but the placeholder solution is nicer I learned. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
$name = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? ($_POST['name'] == 'your name' ? '' : $_POST['name']) : '';
$name = check_input($name, "Please enter a Name.");
```